# Vue change width and content

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vuejs and depending on whether the user is logged in, I need to adjust the size and content of two divs inside my topbar. 
So if they aren't logged in it should be like this:

```
<div id='search' width="400px"></div><div id="login" width="200px"><img></div>
```

And when they're logged in it should be like this:

```
<div id='search' width="200px"></div><div id="login" width="400px"><div id='somecontent></div><div id='morecontent'></div></div>
```

I know i can achieve this by hardcoding both of them entirely and then using v-if statements but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<div id='search' :style="{width: loggedIn ? '200px' : '400px'}"></div>
<div id="login" :style="{width: loggedIn ? '400px' : '200px'}">
  <div id='somecontent' v-if="loggedIn"></div>
  <div id='morecontent' v-if="loggedIn"></div>
  <img v-if="!loggedIn">
</div>
```

You can bind style in vuejs by using [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)

```
new Vue({
  ...
  data: {
    loggedIn: false
  }
  ...
})
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/dcon1nfz/)

Comment: I was searching to apply width on <img>.
<img :width="[loggedIn ? '50' :'150']" />

Answer (score 15):

create a default width inside your data with the default value, like:

```
data() {
        return {
            myWidth: '200'
        }
    },
```

everytime you login you should change the width value, and then you can do something like this:

```
<div :style="{ width: myWidth + 'px' }" id='search' width="400px"></div>
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the style attribute:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loggedIn: false
  },
  created() {
    /*
    if (CHECK_IF_USER_HAS_LOGGED_IN) {
        this.loggedIn = true
    }
    */
  },
  methods: {
    login() { this.loggedIn = true },
    logout() { this.loggedIn = false }
  }
});
```

```css
#search, #login {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="login()">Log in</button>
  <button v-on:click="logout()">Log out</button>
  <div id='search' v-bind:style="{width: loggedIn ? '400px' : '200px'}">Search Stuff</div>
  <div id="login" v-bind:style="{width: loggedIn ? '200px' : '400px'}">
    <img v-if="!loggedIn" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <template v-if="loggedIn">
      <div id="somecontent">some content</div>
      <div id="morecontent">more content</div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```